# How to resize an IgbDialog in blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, infragistics, ignite-ui

I'm trying to resize an `IgbDialog` in blazor(server side) using Ignite UI components. Unfortunately, I could not resize the element adding width and height to the default component. I apologize for my ignorance. Thanks in advance!

see code: https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-blazor/blazor/components/notifications/dialog

```
"<div class="container vertical">
    <IgbButton @onclick="OnDialogShow" Variant=@ButtonVariant.Contained>Show Dialog</IgbButton>
    <IgbDialog @ref="DialogRef" Title="Confirmation" Width="500px" Height="800px"> 
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete the Annual_Report_2016.pdf and Annual_Report_2017.pdf   
files?</p>
        <IgbButton slot="footer" @onclick="OnDialogHide" Variant=@ButtonVariant.Flat>Cancel</IgbButton>
        <IgbButton slot="footer" @onclick="OnDialogHide" Variant=@ButtonVariant.Flat>OK</IgbButton>
    </IgbDialog>
</div>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the content of the dialog in a `div` and style it.

```
<div class="container vertical">
    <IgbButton @onclick="OnDialogShow" Variant=@ButtonVariant.Contained>Show Dialog</IgbButton>
    <IgbDialog @ref="DialogRef" Title="Confirmation">
        <div style="width:500px;height:500px;">
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete the Annual_Report_2016.pdf and Annual_Report_2017.pdf files?</p>
            <IgbButton slot="footer" @onclick="OnDialogHide" Variant=@ButtonVariant.Flat>Cancel</IgbButton>
            <IgbButton slot="footer" @onclick="OnDialogHide" Variant=@ButtonVariant.Flat>OK</IgbButton>
        </div>
    </IgbDialog>
</div>
```

Comment: @thedarkknight NP! Although technically the Width and Height properties of the IgbDialog like in your question seems like the logical way it should work. If you're paying for the library then I suggest raising an issue.

Comment: Absolutely! you're right!